# Restrict Template Function

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a sample program at http://codepad.org/ko8vVCDF that uses a template function.

How do I retrict the template function to only use numbers? (int, double etc.)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    template <typename T>
T sum(vector<T>& a)
{
    T result = 0;
    int size = a.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result += a[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> int_values;
    int_values.push_back(2);
    int_values.push_back(3);
    cout << "Integer: " << sum(int_values) << endl;

    vector<double> double_values;
    double_values.push_back(1.5);
    double_values.push_back(2.1);
    cout << "Double: " << sum(double_values);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have to wait until C++0x compliant compilers are available so you can use concepts.

Comment: A comma would be helpful in your question.

Comment: @DanielRodríguez: to be fair, there _was a comma_ in there...

Comment: Can you propose code?

Comment: Unfortunately, concepts were removed from the draft standard in July 2009. Alas, they were deemed not ready for inclusion in C++.

Comment: Can you show pre-July 2009 code, then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ templates that accept only certain types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

Comment: I hate asking this, but can you please unaccept the current answer and accept mine? The current accepted answer is incorrect and not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only way to restrict a template is to make it so that it uses something from the types that you want, that other types don't have.

So, you construct with an int, use + and +=, call a copy constructor, etc.

Any type that has all of these will work with your function -- so, if I create a new type that has these features, your function will work on it -- which is great, isn't it?

If you want to restrict it more, use more functions that only are defined for the type you want.

Another way to implement this is by creating a traits template -- something like this

```
template<class T>
SumTraits
{
public:
  const static bool canUseSum = false;
}
```

And then specialize it for the classes you want to be ok:

```
template<>
class SumTraits<int>
{
  public:
    const static bool canUseSum = true;
};
```

Then in your code, you can write

```
if (!SumTraits<T>::canUseSum) {
   // throw something here
}
```

edit: as mentioned in the comments, you can use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to make it a compile-time check instead of a run-time one

Comment: You can also use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to enforce the condition at compile time.

Comment: This is a runtime check, which is not a good idea since this can be done at compile time instead.

Comment: SFINAE is the solution to this, not BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT

Comment: There are ways to do static asserts oneself. (If you mind using boost) E.g. by using a switch(ASDF) {case 0: case SOMETHINGNOZZERO: break;}

Comment: `The only way to restrict` and a bit later `Another way to ... restrict`. Something's not accurate here ...

Comment: There is also a `static_assert` keyword in C++11 :)

Answer (score 21):

This is possible by using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), and made easier by using helpers from either Boost or C++11

Boost:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_arithmetic.hpp>

template<typename T> 
    typename boost::enable_if<typename boost::is_arithmetic<T>::type, T>::type 
        sum(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;
  T result;
  size_type size = vec.size();
  for(size_type i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    result += vec[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

C++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type 
        sum(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  T result;
  for (auto item : vec)
    result += item;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @curiousguy: In this sniplet I assumed the includes (vector) and usings (std) of the OP.

Comment: @curiousguy: D'oh! I see what you meant now! Fixed it.

Answer (score 19):

You can do something like this:

```
template <class T>
class NumbersOnly
{
private:
    void ValidateType( int    &i ) const {}
    void ValidateType( long   &l ) const {}
    void ValidateType( double &d ) const {}
    void ValidateType( float  &f ) const {}

public:
    NumbersOnly()
    {
       T valid;
       ValidateType( valid );
    };
};
```

You will get an error if you try to create a NumbersOnly that doesn't have a ValidateType overload:

```
NumbersOnly<int> justFine;
NumbersOnly<SomeClass> noDeal;
```

Comment: I briefly thought this was wrong (sorry), but the & in the method signatures is vital - it prevents instantiation with a type that's only convertible to int. So char, unsigned int, and a class that overloads operator int() are all banned as expected.

Comment: As is "long double", which might not be what you want. But that's just a question of listing every arithmetic type from the C++ standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop "_As is "long double", which might not be what you want._" What he wants isn't very clear.

Comment: @Jeff: This is the solution that I like to use in my codes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

That is how you do it.

Comment the template specialization for double for example.. and it will not allow you to call that function with double as parameter. The trick is that if you try to call sum with a type that is not among the specializations of `IsNumber`, then the generic implementation is called, and that implementation makes something not allowed (call a private constructor).

The error message is NOT intuitive unless you rename the `IsNumber` class to something that sounds like an error message.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> struct IsNumber{ 
 private:
 IsNumber(){}
 };

 template<> struct IsNumber<float>{
   IsNumber(){};
 };

 template<> struct IsNumber<double>{
   IsNumber(){};
 };

 template<> struct IsNumber<int>{
   IsNumber(){};
 };

template <typename T>
T sum(vector<T>& a)
{
 IsNumber<T> test;
 T result = 0;
 int size = a.size();
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
  result += a[i];
 }

 return result;
}




int main()
{
 vector<int> int_values;
 int_values.push_back(2);
 int_values.push_back(3);
 cout << "Integer: " << sum(int_values) << endl;

 vector<double> double_values;
 double_values.push_back(1.5);
 double_values.push_back(2.1);
 cout << "Double: " << sum(double_values);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to restrict the types in this case? Templates allow "static duck typing", so anything allowed by what your `sum` function in this case should be allowed. Specifically, the only operation required of `T` is add-assignment and initialisation by 0, so any type that supports those two operations would work. That's the beauty of templates.

(If you changed your initialiser to `T result = T();` or the like, then it would work for both numbers and strings, too.)

Comment: To expand on "type safe", I'd say "to prevent me having to document and stick to a limited set of assumptions I make about the behaviour of arithmetic operators and conversions, which non-built-in types might not satisfy". Else you might change the implementation in future and want more assumptions.

Comment: So for example currently it uses +=. If it later changes to use +, then a user whose type only supports += will come a cropper. For an example this simple, I can't think of any other plausible implementation change, and overloading += and not + is asking for trouble anyway, but hopefully yswim.

Comment: onebyone: Hear, hear! Documenting the "interface" is the way to go, works much the same way as with dynamic languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into type traits (use boost, wait for C++0x or create your own).

I found the following on google: http://artins.org/ben/programming/mactechgrp-artin-cpp-type-traits.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there's no need to make it more stringent.  Have a look at the string version (using the default constructor style advised by Chris Jester-Young) [here](http://codepad.org/fMkc0zHx)...

Take care, too, for overflows - you might need a bigger type to contain intermediate results (or output results).  Welcome to the realm of meta-programming, then :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want our templated add function can only accepts int and floats, We can do something like below. Can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/qa4z968hP

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

template <typename T> struct restrict_type {};
template<> struct restrict_type<float> {typedef float type;};
template<> struct restrict_type<int> {typedef int type;};

template<typename T>
typename restrict_type<T>::type add(T val1, T val2){
    return val1 + val2;
}

int main()
{
    fmt::print("{}\n", add(12, 30));
    fmt::print("{}\n", add(12.5f, 30.9f));
}
```