# How do you constrain a template to only accept certain types

Tags: c++, templates, constraints

In Java you can define generic class that accepts only types that extend a class of your choice:

```java
public class ObservableList<T extends List> {
    /* ... */
}
```

This is done using `extends` keyword.

Is there some simple equivalent to this keyword in C++?

Comment: quite old question already...I feel what is missing here (also from the answers) is that Java generics arent really an equivalent of templates in C++. There are similarities, but imho one should be careful with directly translating a java solution to C++ just to realize that they are maybe made for different kinds of problems ;)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I suggest using Boost's [static assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) feature in concert with [`is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) from the Boost Type Traits library:

```
template<typename T>
class ObservableList {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_base_of<List, T>::value)); //Yes, the double parentheses are needed, otherwise the comma will be seen as macro argument separator
    ...
};
```

In some other, simpler cases, you can simply forward-declare a global template, but only define (explicitly or partially specialise) it for the valid types:

```
template<typename T> class my_template;     // Declare, but don't define

// int is a valid type
template<> class my_template<int> {
    ...
};

// All pointer types are valid
template<typename T> class my_template<T*> {
    ...
};

// All other types are invalid, and will cause linker error messages.
```

**[Minor EDIT 6/12/2013: Using a declared-but-not-defined template will result in *linker*, not compiler, error messages.]**

Comment: Static asserts are nice as well. :)

Comment: I don't want Boost, I am on embedded platform/phone. Would `template<> my_template<myBaseType> {` perform partial specialisation for all types derived from `myBaseType` too?

Comment: @John: I'm afraid that specialisation would only match `myBaseType` exactly.  Before dismissing Boost, you should know that most of it is header-only template code -- so there's no memory or time cost at runtime for things you don't use.  Also the particular things you'd be using here (`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT()` and `is_base_of<>`) can be implemented using only *declarations* (i.e. no actual *definitions* of functions or variables) so they won't take any space or time either.

Comment: C++11 has come. Now we can use `static_assert(std::is_base_of<List, T>::value, "T must extend list")`.

Comment: I like this answer because the solution shows a way to pull it off if you don't have boost or don't wish to use boost.  I work in embedded space using special GCC tool-chain from a vendor with no support for boost but supports templates.  thumbs up!

Comment: I tried imitating crazy Java generics use: `class UnitType<T extends UnitType<T>>` ... `class Unit<T extends UnitType<T>>` and I couldn't get it to work.  Fortunately, I realized such madness wouldn't be necessary with C++ templates :)

Comment: Thanks for the note about double parenthesis being necessary. I was having compiler errors trying to use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT in combination with is_base_of until I found your answer (I was using single parenthesis).

Comment: BTW, the reason the double parenthesis is necessary is that BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT is a macro and the extra parenthesis prevent the preprocessor from interpreting the comma within the is_base_of function arguments as a 2nd macro argument.

Comment: How use template in second example? Full code please.

Comment: @Andreyua: I don't really understand what is missing.  You could try declaring a variable `my_template<int> x;` or `my_template<float**> y;` and verify that the compiler allows these, and then declare a variable `my_template<char> z;` and verify that it doesn't.

Answer (score 192):

This typically is unwarranted in C++, as other answers here have noted. In C++ we tend to define generic types based on other constraints other than "inherits from this class". If you really wanted to do that, it's quite easy to do in C++11 and `<type_traits>`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class observable_list {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<list, T>::value, "T must inherit from list");
    // code here..
};
```

This breaks a lot of the concepts that people expect in C++ though. It's better to use tricks like defining your own traits. For example, maybe `observable_list` wants to accept any type of container that has the typedefs `const_iterator` and a `begin` and `end` member function that returns `const_iterator`. If you restrict this to classes that inherit from `list` then a user who has their own type that doesn't inherit from `list` but provides these member functions and typedefs would be unable to use your `observable_list`.

There are two solutions to this issue, one of them is to not constrain anything and rely on duck typing. A big con to this solution is that it involves a massive amount of errors that can be hard for users to grok. Another solution is to define traits to constrain the type provided to meet the interface requirements. The big con for this solution is that involves extra writing which can be seen as annoying. However, the positive side is that you will be able to write your own error messages a la `static_assert`.

For completeness, the solution to the example above is given:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...>
struct void_ {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename... Args>
using Void = typename void_<Args...>::type;

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_const_iterator : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_const_iterator<T, Void<typename T::const_iterator>> : std::true_type {};

struct has_begin_end_impl {
    template<typename T, typename Begin = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().begin()),
                         typename End   = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().end())>
    static std::true_type test(int);
    template<typename...>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template<typename T>
struct has_begin_end : decltype(has_begin_end_impl::test<T>(0)) {};

template<typename T>
class observable_list {
    static_assert(has_const_iterator<T>::value, "Must have a const_iterator typedef");
    static_assert(has_begin_end<T>::value, "Must have begin and end member functions");
    // code here...
};
```

There are a lot of concepts shown in the example above that showcase C++11's features. Some search terms for the curious are variadic templates, SFINAE, expression SFINAE, and type traits.

Comment: I never realized C++ templates use duck typing until today.  Kind of bizarre!

Comment: Given the extensive policy constraints **C++** introduced to **C**, not sure why `template<class T:list>` is such an offending concept. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If someone wonders what is  `template<typename... Args>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Answer (score 78):

The simple solution, which no one have mentioned yet, is to just ignore the problem. If I try to use an `int` as a template type in a function template that expects a container class such as vector or list, then I will get a compile error. Crude and simple, but it solves the problem. The compiler will try to use the type you specify, and if that fails, it generates a compile error.

The only problem with that is that the error messages you get are going to be tricky to read. It is nevertheless a very common way to do this. The standard library is full of function or class templates that expect certain behavior from the template type, and do nothing to check that the types used are valid.

If you want nicer error messages (or if you want to catch cases that wouldn't produce a compiler error, but still don't make sense) you can, depending on how complex you want to make it, use either Boost's static assert or the Boost concept_check library.

With an up-to-date compiler you have a built_in `static_assert`, which could be used instead.

Comment: Yes, I always thought that templates are the closest thing to duck typing in C++. If it has all the elements necessary for a template, it can be used in a template.

Comment: @John: I'm sorry, I can't make head or tails of that. Which type is `T`, and from where is this code called? Without some context, I have no chance of understanding that code snippet. But what I said is true. If you try to call `toString()` on a type which does not have a `toString` member function, then you'll get a compile error.

Comment: @John: next time, perhaps you should be a bit less trigger-happy downvoting people when the problem is in your code

Comment: @jalf, ok. +1. This was a great answer just trying to make it the best. Sorry for misreading. I thought we were talking about using the type as a parameter for classes not for function templates, which I suppose are members of the former but need invoking for the compiler to flag.

Answer (score 15):

We can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):
([`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) can be removed, the above classes can be custom-implemented or used from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) if we cannot reference [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types))

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>

class Base {};
class Derived: public Base {};

#if 0   // wrapper
template <class T> class MyClass /* where T:Base */ {
private:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T is not derived from Base");
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, T>::type inner;
};
#elif 0 // base class
template <class T> class MyClass: /* where T:Base */
    protected std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, T>::type {
private:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T is not derived from Base");
};
#elif 1 // list-of
template <class T> class MyClass /* where T:list<Base> */ {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, typename T::value_type>::value , "T::value_type is not derived from Base");
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type base; 
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type::value_type value_type;

};
#endif

int main() {
#if 0   // wrapper or base-class
    MyClass<Derived> derived;
    MyClass<Base> base;
//  error:
    MyClass<int> wrong;
#elif 1 // list-of
    MyClass<std::list<Derived>> derived;
    MyClass<std::list<Base>> base;
//  error:
    MyClass<std::list<int>> wrong;
#endif
//  all of the static_asserts if not commented out
//  or "error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, ...>’ pointing to:
//  1. inner
//  2. MyClass
//  3. base + value_type
}
```

Answer (score 14):

An equivalent that only accepts types T derived from type List looks like

```
template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<List, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class ObservableList
{
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 13):

**C++20 concept usage example**

Adapted from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints, you could just do some duck typing:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>

struct ClassWithMyFunc {
    int myFunc() {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct ClassWithoutMyFunc {};

// Concept HasMyFunc: type 'T' has `.myFunc` and
// its return is convertible to int.
template<typename T>
concept HasMyFunc= requires(T a) {
    { a.myFunc() } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
};

// Constrained function template
template<HasMyFunc T>
int f(T t) {
    return t.myFunc() + 1;
}

int main() {
    assert(f(ClassWithMyFunc()) == 2);
    // assert(f(ClassWithoutMyFunc()) == 2);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

If we uncomment the line `// assert(f(ClassWithoutMyFunc()) == 2);`, it fails as desired with:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/cassert:44,
                 from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:34: error: use of function ‘int f(T) [with T = ClassWithoutMyFunc]’ with unsatisfied constraints
   27 |     assert(f(ClassWithoutMyFunc()) == 2);
      |                                  ^
main.cpp:21:5: note: declared here
   21 | int f(T t) {
      |     ^
main.cpp:21:5: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int f(T) [with T = ClassWithoutMyFunc]’:
main.cpp:27:5:   required from here
main.cpp:15:9:   required for the satisfaction of ‘HasMyFunc<T>’ [with T = ClassWithoutMyFunc]
main.cpp:15:20:   in requirements with ‘T a’ [with T = ClassWithoutMyFunc]
main.cpp:16:15: note: the required expression ‘a.myFunc()’ is invalid
   16 |     { a.myFunc() } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
```

**Require multiple base classes**

If you really want to require one of certain base classes:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

struct Base1 {};
struct Base2 {};

struct Derived1 : public Base1 {};
struct Derived2 : public Base2 {};

struct NotDerived {};

template<typename T>
concept HasBase1Or2= std::is_base_of<Base1, T>::value || std::is_base_of<Base2, T>::value;

template<HasBase1Or2 T>
void f(T) {}

int main() {
    f(Derived1());
    f(Derived2());
    // f(NotDerived());
}
```

If we uncomment the line `// f(NotDerived());` it fails as desired with:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:19: error: use of function ‘void f(T) [with T = NotDerived]’ with unsatisfied constraints
   22 |     f(NotDerived());
      |                   ^
main.cpp:17:6: note: declared here
   17 | void f(T) {}
      |      ^
main.cpp:17:6: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void f(T) [with T = NotDerived]’:
main.cpp:22:19:   required from here
main.cpp:13:9:   required for the satisfaction of ‘HasBase1Or2<T>’ [with T = NotDerived]
main.cpp:13:55: note: no operand of the disjunction is satisfied
   13 | concept HasBase1Or2= std::is_base_of<Base1, T>::value ||
      |                                                 ~~~~~~^~
   14 |                      std::is_base_of<Base2, T>::value;
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
```

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04 GCC 10.3.0.

GCC 10 appears to have implemented it: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html and you can get it [as a PPA on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu/1163021#1163021). https://godbolt.org/ GCC 10.1 did not recognize `concept` however on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know this isn't currently possible in C++. However, there are plans to add a feature called "concepts" in the new C++0x standard that provide the functionality that you're looking for. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) about C++ Concepts will explain it in more detail.

I know this doesn't fix your immediate problem but there are some C++ compilers that have already started to add features from the new standard, so it might be possible to find a compiler that has already implemented the concepts feature.

Comment: Concepts have been dropped from the standard unfortunately.

Comment: Constraints and concepts should be adopted for C++20.

Comment: It is possible even without concepts, using `static_assert` and SFINAE, as the other answers show. The remaining issue for somebody coming from Java or C#, or Haskell(...) is that the C++20 compiler does not do [definition checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definition-checking) against the required concepts, which Java and C# do.

Answer (score 11):

I think all prior answers have lost sight of the forest for the trees.

Java generics *are not the same as templates*; they use *type erasure*, which is a **dynamic technique**, rather than *compile time polymorphism*, which is **static technique**. It should be obvious why these two very different tactics do not gel well.

Rather than attempt to use a compile time construct to simulate a run time one, let's look at what `extends` actually does: [according to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494380/whats-the-difference-between-the-implements-extends-keywords-in-java) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), extends is used to indicate subclassing.

C++ also supports subclassing.

You also show a container class, which is using type erasure in the form of a generic, and extends to perform a type check. In C++, you have to do the type erasure machinery yourself, which is simple: make a pointer to the superclass.

Let's wrap it into a typedef, to make it easier to use, rather than make a whole class, et voila:

`typedef std::list<superclass*> subclasses_of_superclass_only_list;`

For example:

```
class Shape { };
class Triangle : public Shape { };

typedef std::list<Shape*> only_shapes_list;
only_shapes_list shapes;

shapes.push_back(new Triangle()); // Works, triangle is kind of shape
shapes.push_back(new int(30)); // Error, int's are not shapes
```

Now, it seems List is an interface, representing a sort of collection. An interface in C++ would merely be an abstract class, that is, a class that implements nothing but pure virtual methods. Using this method, you could easily implement your java example in C++, without any Concepts or template specializations. It would also perform as slow as Java style generics due to the virtual table look ups, but this can often be an acceptable loss.

Comment: I'm not a fan of answers that use phrases such as "it  should be obvious," or "everyone knows", and then go on to explain what is obvious or universally known. Obvious is relative to context, experience and context of experience. Such statements are inherently rude.

Comment: @DavidLively It's about two years too late to be criticizing this answer for etiquette, but I also disagree with you in this specific instance; I explained why they two techniques don't go together _before_ stating it was obvious, not after. I provided the context, and then said the conclusion from that context was obvious. That doesn't exactly fit your mold.

Comment: The author of this answer said something was obvious after doing some heavy lifting. I do not think the author intended to say the solution was obvious.

Comment: It is not at all obvious why the two techniques do not play well together, or even that they have to, seeing as template parameter constraints dpmhave to be the same as either.

Comment: <eyeroll @ edit timeouot> It is not at all obvious why the two techniques do not play well together, or even that they have to, seeing template parameter constraints don't have to be the same as either. Even Strousstrup was amazed that the problem wasn't address in C++0x, given that it was top of his list of priorities. The template metaprogramming bodge that has been provided in it's place is inexcusable. A concise way to specify "matching classes must implement these methods (virtually or non-virtually)" would have addressed 99% of requirements for non-STL programmers. (35+ year C++ veteran)

Answer (score 9):

Executive summary: Don't do that.

j_random_hacker's answer tells you *how* to do this. However, I would also like to point out that you should *not* do this. The whole point of templates is that they can accept any compatible type, and Java style type constraints break that.

Java's type constraints are a bug not a feature. They are there because Java does type erasure on generics, so Java can't figure out how to call methods based on the value of type parameters alone.

C++ on the other hand has no such restriction. Template parameter types can be any type compatible with the operations they are used with. There doesn't have to be a common base class. This is similar to Python's "Duck Typing," but done at compile time.

A simple example showing the power of templates:

```
// Sum a vector of some type.
// Example:
// int total = sum({1,2,3,4,5});
template <typename T>
T sum(const vector<T>& vec) {
    T total = T();
    for (const T& x : vec) {
        total += x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

This sum function can sum a vector of any type that support the correct operations. It works with both primitives like int/long/float/double, and user defined numeric types that overload the += operator. Heck, you can even use this function to join strings, since they support +=.

No boxing/unboxing of primitives is necessary.

Note that it also constructs new instances of T using T(). This is trivial in C++ using implicit interfaces, but not really possible in Java with type constraints.

While C++ templates don't have explicit type constraints, they are still type safe, and will not compile with code that does not support the correct operations.

Comment: If you are suggesting never specializing templates can you also explain why it is in the language?

Comment: I get your point, but if your template argument must be derived from a specific type, then it's better to have an easy to interpret message from static_assert than the normal compiler error vomit.

Comment: Yes, C++ is more expressive here, but while that's generally a good thing (because we can express more with less), sometimes we want to *deliberately* limit the power we give ourselves, to gain certainty that we fully understand a system.

Comment: @Curg type specialising is useful when you want to be able to take advantage of some thing that can only be done for certain types. for example, a boolean is ~normally~ one byte each, even though one byte can ~normally~ hold 8 bits/booleans; a template collection class can (and in the case of std::map does) specialise for boolean so it can pack the data more tightly to conserve memory.

Comment: Also, to clarify, this answer is not say "never specialise templates" it's saying don't use that feature to try to limit what types can be used with a template.

Comment: If the type has no constraint, then how the IDE can show a list of callable methods of the object? Is the reason of this design that the folks that design C++ only use VIM instead of IDE?

Comment: I'd go so far and argue that _because_ Java has type erasure, it doesn't actually care at runtime. The type restriction is there as a sanity check for the one using the API, to tell the programmer "hey, I'm expecting something that conforms to this sort of interface", so that the programmer can know at a glance what works without having to dig through the source or documentation. It's why we have static analysis at all: to catch human errors.

Answer (score 7):

That's not possible in plain C++, but you can verify template parameters at compile-time through Concept Checking, e.g. using [Boost's BCCL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).

As of C++20, concepts are becoming an [official feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) of the language.

Comment: Well, it *is* possible, but concept checking is still a good idea. :)

Comment: I actually meant that it was not possible in "plain" C++. ;)

Comment: This is false. You could do it with SFINAE in C++98. "Plain" C++ is enough.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Base
{
    struct FooSecurity{};
};

template<class Type>
class Foo
{
    typename Type::FooSecurity If_You_Are_Reading_This_You_Tried_To_Create_An_Instance_Of_Foo_For_An_Invalid_Type;
};
```

Make sure derived classes inherit the FooSecurity structure and the compiler will get upset in all the right places.

Comment: @Zehelvion `Type::FooSecurity` is used in template class. If the class, passed in template argument, hasn't `FooSecurity`, attempting to use it causes an error. It's sure that if class passed in template argument hasn't FooSecurity it isn't derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyword for such type checks, but you can put some code in that will at least fail in an orderly fashion:

(1) If you want a function template to only accept parameters of a certain base class X, assign it to a X reference in your function.
(2) If you want to accept functions but not primitives or vice versa, or you want to filter classes in other ways, call a (empty) template helper function within your function that's only defined for the classes you want to accept.

You can use (1) and (2) also in member functions of a class to force these type checks on the entire class.

You can probably put it into some smart Macro to ease your pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some simple equivalent to this keyword in C++?

No.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there might be adequate (or even better) substitutes.

I've looked through some STL code (on linux, I think it's the one deriving from SGI's implementation).  It has "concept assertions"; for instance, if you require a type which understands `*x` and `++x`, the concept assertion would contain that code in a do-nothing function (or something similar).  It does require some overhead, so it might be smart to put it in a macro whose definition depends on `#ifdef debug`.

If the subclass relationship is really what you want to know about, you could assert in the constructor that `T instanceof list` (except it's "spelled" differently in C++).  That way, you can test your way out of the compiler not being able to check it for you.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could create your template reading something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class ObservableList {
  std::list<T> contained_data;
};
```

This will however make the restriction implicit, plus you can't just supply anything that looks like a list. There are other ways to restrict the container types used, for example by making use of specific iterator types that do not exist in all containers but again this is more an implicit than an explicit restriction.

To the best of my knowledge a construct that would mirror the statement Java statement to its full extent does not exist in current standard.

There are ways to restrict the types you can use inside a template you write by using specific typedefs inside your template. This will ensure that the compilation of the template specialisation for a type that does not include that particular typedef will fail, so you can selectively support/not support certain types.

In C++11, the introduction of concepts should make this easier but I don't think it'll do exactly what you'd want either.