# Templated construction of non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, specialization

I have a class that has common members but needs to be constructed in a finite number of ways based on an enumeration.  Each type is known at compile time, so I am thinking templates make sense here.  I know I can solve this with constructor specialization, e.g.:

```
enum SensorTypes{GPS,Radar,ShaftEncoder};

template<SensorTypes>
class Sensor
{
public:
    Sensor(unsigned char* rawdata){//Format of rawdata depends on SensorTypes};
private:
    double speed;
    double time;
}
template<> Sensor<GPS>::Sensor(unsigned char* rawdata){speed = (double)rawdata[0];}
```

The problem is I have legacy code which must accept `Sensor` classes not `Sensor<GPS>` etc.  How can I achieve similar compile time construction while maintaining a single class type.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/874298/918124

Comment: Your example should not compile.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Sensor`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems simple enough at first, just use a templated constructor in the `Sensor` class.

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace sensorKind {
    struct GPS {};
    struct Radar {};
    struct ShaftEncoder {};
}

class Sensor
{
public:
    template< class Kind >
    Sensor( Kind, unsigned char const* rawdata );
private:
    double speed_;
    double time_;
};

template<>
Sensor::Sensor(
    sensorKind::GPS,
    unsigned char const* rawData
    )
{
    printf( "Sensor<GPS> object created.\n" );
}

template<>
Sensor::Sensor(
    sensorKind::Radar,
    unsigned char const* rawData
    )
{
    printf( "Sensor<Radar> object created.\n" );
}

int main()
{
    Sensor  aGPSSensor( sensorKind::GPS(), 0 );
    Sensor  aRadarSensor( sensorKind::Radar(), 0 );
}
```

But at this point it's easy to see that the "type-argument" is really describing the rawdata, and nothing else.

So really, it should be the rawdata argument that should be typed.

Making the rawdata more strictly typed also helps you avoid foul-ups were e.g. radar rawdata is treated as GPS rawdata.

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace sensor {
    struct Kind {
        enum  Enum{ gps, radar, shaftEncoder };
    };

    template< Kind::Enum aKind >
    class DataFrom 
    {
    public:
        static Kind::Enum const kind = aKind;

        unsigned char const* ptr() const { return 0; }
        DataFrom() {}
    };
}  // namespace sensor

class Sensor
{
public:
    typedef sensor::Kind    Kind;

    template< class DataKind >
    explicit Sensor(  DataKind const& rawData );
private:
    double speed_;
    double time_;
};

template<>
Sensor::Sensor( sensor::DataFrom< Kind::gps > const& rawData )
{
    printf( "%s\n", "Sensor<GPS> object created." );
}

template<>
Sensor::Sensor( sensor::DataFrom< Kind::radar > const& rawData )
{
    printf( "%s\n", "Sensor<Radar> object created." );
}

int main()
{
    sensor::DataFrom< sensor::Kind::gps >   gpsData;
    sensor::DataFrom< sensor::Kind::radar > radarData;

    Sensor  aGPSSensor( gpsData );
    Sensor  aRadarSensor( radarData );
}
```

Design-wise, this is partitioning into rawdata providers and rawdata interpreters (the `Sensor` class is evidently a rawdata interpreter).

That design is implied by the question, but if *may* be that it could be beneficial to move the interpretation knowledge closer to the data sources.

I.e., to move the interpretation of e.g. radar data out of the `Sensor` constructor and class, and into the class carrying radar rawdata.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific needs, you may be able to create a non-template base class and derive the template-specific version, using virtual methods to select the right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems simple enough, just have your template class derive from the existing `Sensor` class.

```
template<SensorTypes>
class DerivedSensor : public Sensor
{
public:
    DerivedSensor(unsigned char* rawdata){//Format of rawdata depends on SensorTypes};
};
```

Comment: I am really looking for a template solution that fits with the legacy code (i.e. accepts `Sensor` not `Sensor<GPS>` or `DerivedSensor` types) and avoids virtual methods, having to upcast or proliferating derived classes for longer enumerations.

Comment: @Michael George, maybe I don't understand the question - you want to create `Sensor` objects but you want them to have different constructors based on the enumeration, correct? Is there something other than the constructor that depends on the enumeration?