# multi inheriting a struct from struct and template struct, ordering matters when accessing base non-template struct data

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

struct base_C_event {
    const char* ev;
    const char* da;
};

template <class T>
struct ref_counter {

    private:
        std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t> _counter;
};

struct derived_event : ref_counter<derived_event>, base_C_event {

    derived_event() : event_type(), event_data() {
        ev = event_type.c_str();
        da = event_data.c_str();
    }

    std::string event_type;
    std::string event_data;
};

struct derived_event2 : base_C_event, ref_counter<derived_event2> {
    derived_event2() : event_type(), event_data() {
        ev = event_type.c_str();
        da = event_data.c_str();
    }

    std::string event_type;
    std::string event_data;
};

struct some_cool_event {
    int type;
    void* payload;
};

void OnEvent(const some_cool_event* event) {
    auto e = static_cast<base_C_event*>(event->payload); //...and then shows itself here
    printf("%s - %s\n", e->ev, e->da);
}

int main() {
    derived_event evt;
    evt.event_type = "type";
    evt.event_data = "Hello World";

    derived_event2 evt2;
    evt2.event_type = "hi";
    evt2.event_data = "there";

    some_cool_event my_event;
    my_event.type = 1;
    my_event.payload = &evt; //Problem starts here...
    OnEvent(&my_event);

    my_event.type = 2;
    my_event.payload = &evt2;
    OnEvent(&my_event);

    return 0;
}
```

output: (compiled with g++)

(null) - type

type - Hello World

now, in my real environment (XCode) the ordering of inheritance for `derived_event` causes a BADACCESS exception; with g++ it just produces (null) as shown in the output.

however, the ordering for `derived_event2` works just fine.

The way i understand the standard, the order of multiple inheritance effects the order of constructors and destructors, and also the layout of the memory.  Can anyone explain what is happening here?

EDIT:
I have actually figured this out.  The line that sets the event object to the void* payload, and then the ensuing static_cast<> back to the base type... seems to invalidate the first pointer (`ev`) because the struct becomes just a memory layout at that point, so the pointers are getting set to the first two pointer size chunks...  in this case `std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t>` and then the base_C_event.  so the cast is grabbing the data for the std::atomic and using that as the pointer address for `ev`, and what was originally `ev` in the derived object is now what `da` points at.

I unfortunately in my real scenario can't use composition for the `base_C_event` in my `derived_event` and send that.  that's why the refcounting is there, so i have to send the derived object so that later on in a callback i can decrement the refcount.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: what is `ptr_to_const_D` §? and why casting ?

Comment: `static_cast<A*>(ptr_to_const_D)` shouldn't compile if `ptr_to_const_D` is a `D const *`.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Also related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789326/when-is-static-cast-safe-when-you-are-using-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @Jarod42 Casting: Because otherwise, type of A_ptr would be D* - ignoring the possible constness problem... Another example of bad usage of auto, I'd say, though. `A* a_ptr = d_ptr;` would have been easier and clearer...

Comment: Tried the code myself, no problem at all (linux, GCC 7.2.0)... Have you assured that `ev` member actually points to a valid address?

Comment: i updated the question to have a more complete code example, which shows why i needed to do the cast

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes it points to a valid address.  i have alternatively allocated a new char[], and then deleted it in the destructor to absolutely make sure, and i get the same thing.  the order of the inheritance makes the access in OnEvent successful or crash, as stated in the question.

Comment: @hydronics311 Still cannot reproduce. Are you sure that the argument to `onEvent` really is of type `D*`? It is absolutely essential that you provide a [mcve], as denoted already. Complete in this respect means: we just need to copy/paste the entire sample you provided and can reproduce (verifiable!) the error. (Minimal means that you left out anything that is not necessary to produce the error.)

Comment: @Aconcagua: `ptr_to_const_D` is in fact a `void*`, contrary to what the name might suggest :-/ (so the need of cast, but also the error with the bad cast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I think I see where the problem lies:

```
struct D : B<D>, A { };
```

This way you inherit both a `B<D>` and `a A` instance. Effectively, this ressembles something like this:

```
struct D
{
    B<D> implicitly_inherited_B_D;
    A    implicitly_inherited_A;
};
```

You now do the following:

```
D* d    = new D();
void* v = d;
A* a    = static_cast<A*>(v);
```

Problem is: `v` now points to the `D` instance, which shares its address with the inherited `B<D>` instance. But you cast the pointer back to `A*`, however, `D`s `A` has an offset. So what you do corresponds to:

```
D* d    = new D();
void* v = &d->implicitly_inherited_B_D;
A* a    = static_cast<A*>(v);
// or equivalent:
A* aa   = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&d->implicitly_inherited_B_D);
```

This is bound to fail...

If you want to cast back to `A*`, you need to make sure that your pointer actually points to the inherited `A` within `D` - which is quite easy:

```
D* d    = new D();
void* v = static_cast<A*>(d);
// now this will work fine (v points to D's A part):
A* a    = static_cast<A*>(v);
D* dd   = static_cast<D*>(a); // even this one, original object was constructed as D
```

For comparison:

```
D* d  = new D();
A* a  = d;
D* ds = static_cast<D*>(a);
D* dr = reinterpret_cast<D*>(a); // actually undefined behaviour!!!

std::cout << d << std::endl << a << std::endl << ds << std::endl << dr << std::endl;
```

Assuming address of `d` is 0x10001000 and `A` within `D` has an offset of 8(`sizeof(B<D>` + possibly fill bytes for alignment), you'd see an output like this:

```
10001000
10001008
10001000
10001008
```

Note that the last line originates from the `D*` pointer received via reinterpret_cast!

Final note: Be aware that members can be rearranged - members declared first preceding members declared afterwards only is guaranteed for members within the same accessibility class (public/protected/private), *between* these sections, compiler is allowed to re-arrange. So in general you only can be safe if you go back from `void*` the same way you used for getting there:

```
void* v = d; // -> need to go back via static_cast<D*>!

A* a    = static_cast<A*>(v);    // requires v = static_cast<A*>(d);
B<D>* d = static_cast<B<D>*>(v); // requires v = static_cast<B<D>*>(d);
```

Anything else is undefined behaviour (be aware that the matter gets even worse as soon as virtual classes are involved, as then additionally there are the vtable pointers...).

Comment: this was exactly the case.  the offset from the void* cast is what i was seeing.  i was able to update the code to do the proper cast on both sides of where I use the pointer and all is well, order of inheritance no longer matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you cast a pointer to `void *` then always do the exact inverse cast when casting back to actual type.

So if you have :

```
D *d = new D;
void *v = d;  // Here D* is casted to void *
```

When you get back the pointer, use the inverse cast. The following example are correct:

```
D *d2 = static_cast<D *>(v);
A *a2 = static_cast<D *>(v);
B<D> *b2 = static_cast<D *>(v);
```

Even better, if you can, try to avoid using `void *`. It can easily lead to hard-to-find bugs and this is even worst when using multiple inheritance.

If you have to use `void *`, then try do to it as locally as possible in the code so that ideally the conversion is done exactly at one place in the code for each direction.

```
class VoidMember
{
public:
    void set(D *d) { v = d; }
    D *get() { return static_cast<D *>(v);

private:
    // In reality, you would not store a void like that but assume this is stored in 
    // a library / API that use `void *`
    void *v;
};
```

While casting to other types might sometime works, it should be avoided as it make the code more fragile if code is refactored at some point like reordering base classes.

Comment: this answer was also helpful to me; i chose the other one as the proper answer since it was a little more verbose in explaining everything and having slightly more in-depth examples.  Thanks @Phil1970, this was still very helpful.