# What's the difference between the implements & extends keywords in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, implements

What's the difference between the following keywords in Java: `implements`, `extends`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An `interface` is an abstract specification of how a `class` should behave whilst a `class` is a concrete implementation of such a specification.

Therefore, when you write `implements` you're saying that you are fulfilling some abstract specification in the implementation you've written.

`extends` means that you take either an implementation (`class`) or specification (`interface`) and add to it with different or new functionality (or change the specification of its behaviour), thus modifying its behaviour and *extend*-ing it.

Answer (score 12):

a class extends another class and implements interface. interface extends another interface.
Interface hasn't any implemented methods all defined methods are empty so if class inherits from the interface it should **implement** it's methods. But if Class1 inherits from Class2 then it already have some working methods (from Class2) and just **extends** Class2.