# Relationship between class and iterator interface

Tags: java, class, iterator

Will a class become an iterator object itself if it implements an iterator interface.

For example,

```
public class StringGridIterator implements Iterator<String>{


    //some methods here...


}
```

or Do I need to specifically create a variable reference to an iterator object that will iterate through a certain `String` objects?

like this...

```
Iterator<String> it = object.iterator();
```

I don't know if this is clear enough for you to understand since I am still struggling with understanding Java concept like class and object myself.. Just leave a comment if you don't understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: [Java inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: [What is inheritance?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html)

Comment: [Classes and objects.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: Implement Iterator ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class will not become an Iterator object by implementation. You may be thinking of extending a class. (See: [What's the difference between the implements & extends keywords in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494380/whats-the-difference-between-the-implements-extends-keywords-in-java)).

From your examples, it looks like you are attempting to do 2 different things: class inheritance vs. an iterator object. The `.iterator()` method returns an Iterator containing the elements of your object.