# Can i partially specizlize template for not all non-type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

```
template<int, int> 
struct T;

template<> 
struct T<?, ?> {};
```

i want this to work

```
typedef T<1, 0> t;
```

and this to cause compile time error

```
typedef T<1, 2> t;
```

EDIT, i mean i want second parameter to be 0. and i can't use C++11 features.

Comment: Sure, but what's the condition for failing ? or do you want just specific numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ templates that accept only certain types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

Comment: If you want the second parameter to be 0, why not just leave it out?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche The actual argument might be an expression and this be a mechanism to enforce the expression to evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quesiton is not too clear. Are you looking for this?

```
template <int, int>
struct T;

template<int x>
struct T<x, 0>
{
  // Definition of the struct for the allowed case
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[static_assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293588.aspx)** to assert the template arguments.

```
template<int A, int B> 
struct T
{
   static_assert(A > B, "Raised error because A is not bigger than B)";
}
```