# how to only enable this function for string or stringpiece

Tags: c++, enable-if

I have a template function, let's say:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T input) {
    // some funny processing
}
```

I only want to enable this function for T == string or T == stringpiece.
How do I do that using std::enable_if ???

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless `string` is a literal. And if then, you might want to use `strcmp`.

Comment: check `std::enable_if`. @remyabel how does this relate to `strcmp` or string literal?

Comment: In general, you do not want to do this.  If the function attempts to use a function that requires it to be a `string`, and you attempt to instantiate it as an `int`, it will not compile.  If the function does not do anything special with a given type, it should be left generic enough to be used with any compatible type.

Comment: @Bryan I misunderstood. I thought he meant pass in a const char* as T and compare it with some given value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ templates that accept only certain types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

Answer (score 4):

You can just use overloading for this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T);

void foo(string str) { }

void foo(stringpiece sp) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_same` to check two types are the same and then use `enable_if` in the return type of the function:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct stringpiece {
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::string, T>::value || std::is_same<stringpiece, T>::value>::type
foo(T input) {
  // Your stuff here
  (void)input;
}

int main() {
  foo(stringpiece());
  foo(std::string(""));
}
```