# Why is it bad to impose type constraints on templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types) the OP asked about limiting what classes a template will accept. A summary of the sentiment that followed is that the equivalent facility in Java is bad; and don't do this.

I don't understand why this is bad. Duck typing is certainly a powerful tool; but in my mind it lends itself confusing runtime issues when a class looks *close* (same function names) but has slightly different behavior. And you can't necessarily rely on compile time checking because of examples like this:

```
struct One { int a; int b };
struct Two { int a; };

template <class T>
class Worker{
    T data;

    void print() { cout << data.a << endl; }

    template <class X>
    void usually_important () { int a = data.a; int b = data.b; }
}

int main() {
    Worker<Two> w;
    w.print();
}
```

Type `Two` will allow `Worker` to compile *only* if `usually_important` is not called. This could lead to some instantiations of `Worker` compiling and others not even in the same program.

In a case like this, though. The responsibility is put on to the designer of `ENGINE` to ensure that it is a valid type (after which they should inherit `ENGINE_BASE`). If they don't, there will be a compiler error. To me this seems much safer while not imposing any restrictions or adding much additional work.

```
class ENGINE_BASE {}; // Empty class, all engines should extend this

template <class ENGINE>
class NeedsAnEngine {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_base_of<ENGINE_BASE, ENGINE>));
    // Do stuff with ENGINE...
};
```

Comment: I admit having all but no experience with Java. From an OO standpoint I see template as offering the ability to modularize classes and make them more generic.

Comment: The comment ^that was in reponse to dissapeared..

Comment: What I find annoying in duck typing is that it's not clearly documented in code what kind of interface is expected. So from user perspective you have to check the implementation or let the compiler guide you with errors, which are both bad ways to handle it IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

This is too long, but it might be informative.

Generics in Java are a type erasure mechanism, and automatic code generation of type casts and type checks.

`template`s in C++ are code generation and pattern matching mechanisms.

You can use C++ `template`s to do what Java generics do with a bit of effort.  `std::function< A(B) >` behaves in a covariant/contravariant fashion with regards to `A` and `B` types and conversion to other `std::function< X(Y) >`.

But the primary design of the two is not the same.

A Java `List<X>` will be a `List<Object>` with some thin wrapping on it so users don't have to do type casts on extraction.  If you pass it as a `List<? extends Bar>`, it again is getting a `List<Object>` in essence, it just has some extra type information that changes how the casts work and which methods can be invoked.  This means you can extract elements from the `List` into a `Bar` and know it works (and check it).  Only one method is generated for all `List<? extends Bar>`.

A C++ `std::vector<X>` is not in essence a `std::vector<Object>` or `std::vector<void*>` or anything else.  Each instance of a C++ `template` is an unrelated type (except template pattern matching).  In fact, `std::vector<bool>` uses a completely different implementation than any other `std::vector` (this is now considered a mistake because the implementation differences "leak" in annoying ways in this case).  Each method and function is generated independently for the particular type you pass it.

In Java, it is assumed that all objects will fit into some hierarchy.  In C++, that is sometimes useful, but it has been discovered it is often ill fitting to a problem.

A C++ container need not inherit from a common interface.  A `std::list<int>` and `std::vector<int>` are unrelated types, but you can act on them uniformly -- they both are sequential containers.

The question "is the argument a sequential container" is a good question.  This allows anyone to implement a sequential container, and such sequential containers can as high performance as hand-crafted C code with utterly different implementations.

If you created a common root `std::container<T>` which all containers inherited from, it would either be full of `virtual` table cruft or it would be useless other than as a tag type.  As a tag type, it would intrusively inject itself into all non-`std` containers, requiring that they inherit from `std::container<T>` to be a real container.

The traits approach instead means that there are specifications as to what a container (sequential, associative, etc) is.  You can test these specifications at compile time, and/or allow types to note that they qualify for certain axioms via traits of some kind.

The C++03/11 standard library does this with iterators.  `std::iterator_traits<T>` is a traits class that exposes iterator information about an arbitrary type `T`.  Someone completely unconnected to the standard library can write their own iterator, and use `std::iterator<...>` to auto-work with `std::iterator_traits`, add their own type aliases manually, or specialize `std::iterator_traits` to pass on the information required.

C++11 goes a step further.  `for( auto&& x : y )` can work with things that where written long before the range-based iteration was designed, without touching the class itself.  You simply write a free `begin` and `end` function in the namespace that the class belongs to that returns a valid forward iterator (note: even invalid forward iterators that are close enough work), and suddenly `for ( auto&& x : y )` starts working.

`std::function< A(B) >` is an example of using these techniques together with type erasure.  It has a constructor that accepts anything that can be copied, destroyed, invoked with `(B)` and whose return type can be converted to `A`.  The types it can take can be completely unrelated -- only that which is required is tested for.

Because of `std::function`s design, we can have lambda invokables that are unrelated types that can be type-erased into a common `std::function` if needed, but when not type erased their invokation action is known from there type.  So a `template` function that takes a lambda knows at the point of invokation what will happen, which makes inlining an easy local operation.

This technique is not new -- it was in C++ since `std::sort`, a high level algorithm that is faster than C's `qsort` due to the ease of inlining invokable objects passed as comparators.

In short, if you need a common runtime type, type erase.  If you need certain properties, test for those properties, don't force a common base.  If you need certain axioms to hold (untestable properties), either document or require callers to claim those properties via tags or traits classes (see how the standard library handles iterator categories -- again, not inheritance).  When in doubt, use free functions with ADL enabled to access properties of your arguments, and have your default free functions use SFINAE to look for a method and invoke if it exists, and fail otherwise.

Such a mechanism removes the central responsibility of a common base class, allows existing classes to be adapted without modification to pass your requirements (if reasonable), places type erasure only where it is needed, avoids `virtual` overhead, and ideally generates clear errors when properties are found to not hold.

If your `ENGINE` has certain properites it needs to pass, write a traits class that tests for those.

If there are properties that cannot be tested for, create tags that describe such properties.  Use specialization of a traits class, or canonical typedefs, to let the class describe which axioms hold for the type.  (See iterator tags).

If you have a type like `ENGINE_BASE`, don't demand it, but instead use it as a helper for said tags and traits and axiom typedefs, like `std::iterator<...>` (you never have to inherit from it, it simply acts as a helper).

Avoid over specifying requirements.  If `usually_important` is never invoked on your `Worker<X>`, probably your `X` doesn't need a `b` in that context.  But do test for properties in a way clearer than "method does not compile".

And sometimes, just punt.  Following such practices might make things harder for you -- so do an easier way.  Most code is written and discarded.  Know when your code will persist, and write it better and more extendably and more maintainably.  Know that you need to practice those techniques on disposable code so you can write it correctly when you have to.

Answer (score 2):

Let me turn the question around on you: Why is it bad that the code compiles for `Two` if `usually_important` isn't called? The type you gave it meets all the needs for that particular instantiation and the compiler will immediately tell you if a particular instantiation no longer meets the interface needed for the needed functionality in the template.

That said if you insist that you need an `Engine` object, don't do it with templates at all, instead treat it as a sort of strategy pattern with a non-template (using this approach enforces at compile time that the user-defined type adheres to a specific interface, not just that it looks like a duck):

```
class Worker
{
public:
    explicit Worker(EngineBase* data) : data_(data) {}
    void print() { cout << data_->a() << endl; }

    template <class X>
    void usually_important () { int a = data_->a(); int b = data_->b(); }

private:
    EngineBase* data_;
}

int main() 
{
    Worker w(new ConcreteEngine);
    w.print();
}
```

Comment: That's kind of my problem with duck typing. What if we don't want `Two` to be allowed ever? On the other hand, why shouldn't it be allowed if it's close enough? Whose fault is it if `Two` breaks the code; the library writer for allowing it or the client for doing it?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative example using interfaces and pointers? Because I don't know, why is this a better way? The downside to this to me seems like it would be the use of pointers. Both from a "don't use pointers" stance, and for the ability of the compiler to opimize this.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why this is bad. Duck typing is certainly a
>   powerful tool; but in my mind it lends itself confusing runtime issues
>   when a class looks close (same function names) but has slightly
>   different behavior.

The probability that you can define a non-trivial interface and then by accident have another interface that has different semantics but can be substituted is *minimal*. This never, ever happens.

> Type Two will allow Worker to compile only if usually_important is not
>   called.

That is a *good* thing. We depend on it all the time. It makes class templates more flexible.

Matching a compile-time interface is strictly superior to a run-time one. This is because run-time interfaces can't differ in key ways that compile-time ones can (e.g. different types in the interface), and require a bunch of run-time abstraction like dynamic allocation that may be unnecessary.

> In a case like this, though. The responsibility is put on to the
>   designer of ENGINE to ensure that it is a valid type (after which they
>   should inherit ENGINE_BASE). If they don't, there will be a compiler
>   error. To me this seems much safer while not imposing any restrictions
>   or adding much additional work.

It is not safer. It is utterly pointless. It is *stupendously* unlikely that the user will accidentally instantiate the class with the wrong type but it will compile successfully due to circumstantial interface match.

What it really boils down to is this: you should only require what you really *need*. Absolutely definitely must have in order to function. Everything else, don't require it. This is a core tenet of making software maintainable. You cannot possibly imagine what shenanigans I might conceive of long after you have written this class to use it in ways that you never thought it could be used for.