# C++'s version of <? extends AnotherClass>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm just making the jump from Java to C++.  I'm fairly confident with C++ now, and I was trying to make a template class.  Does C++ have a way to guarantee that the template argument extends a certain class?  In Java, I can use class MyClass<? extends AnotherClass>.  If not, is there a way around this limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned Java and C++ are completely different, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386765/why-is-it-bad-to-impose-type-constraints-on-templates-in-c gives some background.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped to clarify.

Comment: Oh dear, it seems this is a duplicate.  I did look around first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "Argument must extend base!");`.

However, note that relative to doing this in Java, in C++ this is nearly totally worthless. There's practically no use case that actually needs it.

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to make an EventListener<T> class and enforce that T extends Event.  Should I use this statement in the ctor?

Comment: If you really need to enforce that T derives from Event. But like I said, that constraint is virtually worthless in C++. If you want to enforce it, it's time to step back and rethink.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I'll accept this as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Be aware that C++ templates are far more powerful beasts than .Net generics, which are slightly more powerful than Java ones. Specifically, they are instantiated at *compile-time* by substituting the *actual template-arguments* you used, *before compiling them*.

Comment: Handy to know, thanks.