# Pure virtual method that returns children of an abstract class?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to make an abstract class, and one of the methods that its children must override should return an instance of the child class.

```
class JsonSerializable {
public:
    virtual <child_of_JsonSerializable> fromJson(string jsonStr) const = 0;
};

class ConcreteSerializable : public JsonSerializable {
public:
    ConcreteSerializable fromJson(string jsonStr) const {
        return ConcreteSerializable();
    }
};
```

I tried using templates following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687399/2599537), but I get an error that `templates may not be virtual`.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for without using raw pointers as the return type?

Comment: Have you looked into [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: looks like what you are looking for is a factory method masqueraded as a member function. What is the problem with returning a base class? All the virtual functions will still behave as expected and the only trouble with that would be the `sizeof`, which means you need to be careful with storing those in arrays or copying around via `memcpy` - both of which are bad ideas in the first place anyway

Comment: @YePhIcK CRTP seems to be the solution to my problem, but I want to understand what you mean. How can I return a base class? The base class is abstract and I get a compilation error if I put it as the return type.

Comment: `struct Derived: Base { Base& get() {return *this;} };` would be one way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to implement something that historically was done using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

```
struct Interface {
    virtual Interface *inflate(std::string const &json) = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

template<typename Child> struct Base: public Interface {
    Interface *inflate(std::string const &json) { return new Child(json); }
};

struct Child: public Base<Child> {
    Child(std::string const &json);
};
```

Comment: are you answering a question with a question? ;-)

Comment: Why are you curious? :D

Comment: Was that your intent to make me smile?

Comment: You should really provide the body of the `Child`'s constructor here, otherwise it's very unclear what is happening

Comment: Hmmm... if only I could. Will a single call to `inflateFromJson(json);` suffice?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an object of an abstract type. And because you cannot create such an object, you also cannot return it. This is the reason why all examples returning a base/derived object, always return a pointer or some reference to the base class

```
struct B {
    virtual B *fromJson(const std::string &jsonStr) const = 0;
};

struct D : public B {
    D(const std::string &jsonStr);
    D *fromJson(const std::string &jsonStr) const;
};

D *D::fromJson(const std::string &jsonStr) const
{
    return new D(jsonStr);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I was hoping there was some trick I could do with smart pointers or templates. CRTP seems like a good solution to my problem so I'll go with that.