# C++ Generics and Polymorphism: is this pattern workable?

Tags: c++, generics, polymorphism

I understand how Polymorphism and Generics interact in other programming languages (Java, C#, Typescript, ect.). In C++ however it feels like a pattern I would like to utilize fails.

In this example I want to have a list of `Name`s which extend `Word`s. I want to pass my list of names into a method which accepts a list of words, but I cannot. I can populate a list of words *with* my names, this however loses the type information, meaning I cannot call any methods inherit to the Name class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

class Word{
    public:
        virtual void say() = 0;
};

class Name : public Word{
    std::string name;
    public:
        Name(std::string name){
            this-> name = name;
        }
        void say() override{
            std::cout << name << std::endl;
        }
        void important_name_function(){
           // Something very important I want to call
        }
};

void say_one(Word* w){
    w-> say();
}

void say_all(std::list<Word*> list){
    for(Word* w: list){
        w-> say();
    }    
}

int main(){
    std::list<Word*> words = {new Name("Kai"), new Name("Ben"), new Name("Sam")};
    say_one(words.front()); //Works, due to the magic of polymorphism
    say_all(words); //Works, due to the magic of polymorphism

    std::list<Name*> names = {new Name("Kai"), new Name("Ben"), new Name("Sam")};
    say_one(names.front()); //STILL works due to the magic of polymorphism AND type information is retained
    say_all(names); //Fails but feels like it shouldn't
}
```

In, for example, Java I would be able to solve this issue by defining say all as

```
static <T extends Word> void say_all (java.util.LinkedList<T> list){
    for(T w:list){
        w.say();
    }  
}
```

However, looking for this solution in C++ gets what to my eyes looks like an ugly solution ([C++ equivalent of using <T extends Class> for a java parameter/return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687305/c-equivalent-of-using-t-extends-class-for-a-java-parameter-return-type))

To me this means that one of the following is true:

- This pattern is inherently undesirable, and should not be pursued.
- The solution I dismissed as ugly is in fact the best solution and/or
- I am incorrectly accessing it as ugly There is another solution to
  creating this pattern

Comment: Have a look at the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and decide if that solves your issues.

Comment: Hi! This solved my immediate issue. However in my implementation (https://pastebin.com/9m5c0xtH) I was unable to figure out how to create a list of `words`. I was only able to create lists of `Names` and then pass that to the methods that ask for lists of "Things extending words". This is 85% of what I need, and I am v. grateful, but I would be curious if I am missing a way to get the perfect solution

Comment: Why not just template the `say_all()` function, like so?  `say_all(std::list<T*> list)`

Comment: You want covariance of types, C++ doesn't support it, because `std::list<X>` is not in any way related to `std::list<Y>`. For all we know there could be specialization for `Y` that make list behave as queue. There isn't one, but compiler cannot know that. There's unfortunate example with `std::vector<bool>` . Covariance can be implemented with conversion operators but `std::list` doesn't have any.

Comment: Also I suggest reading about stack,heap and smart pointers. There should be very few examples where you should ever write `new` by hand. And you should always be very suspicius if you write/see one.

Comment: You wrote *"I want to pass my list of names into a method which accepts a list of words"* but Isn't your java example accepting a list of Names (checking that Name inherits from Word)? You could easily implement a same kind of generic function in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - *I am incorrectly assessing it as ugly*

That.

I don't find the following ugly:

```
template<class T>
void say_all(const std::list<T*>& list) {
    for (T* w : list) {
        w->say();
    }    
}
```

Note that you don't have to restrict `T` at all in your example. Can't really match that in Java.

Only if you actually *need* to restrict `T` to an instance of `Word`:

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Word, T>::value>>
void say_all(const std::list<T*>& list) {
    for (T* w : list) {
        w->say();
    }    
}
```

Or with concepts:

```
template<typename T>
concept IsWord = std::is_base_of<Word, T>::value;

template<class T> requires IsWord<T>
void say_all(const std::list<T*>& list) {
    for(T* w : list) {
        w->say();
    }    
}
```

---

Side notes:

- avoid copying objects unnecessarily by passing them by reference.
- to reduce memory leaks avoid operator `new` and use `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Word>>` and `std::make_unique` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement a generic function similar to java one using [`::std::is_base_of` type trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template
<
    typename x_Word
,   typename x_Enabled = ::std::enable_if_t
    <
        ::std::is_base_of_v<Word, x_Word>
    >
>
auto
say_all(::std::list<x_Word *> & words) -> void
{
    for(auto & p_w: words)
    {
        p_w->say();
    }    
    return;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T6IofmFblqdcsTa0)

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong -- this is something C++ isn't great at. It doesn't currently have an equivalent to Java's bounded type parameters, meaning that if you want that specific level of control over what `say_all` can take, rather than just doing `template<typename T> void say_all(list<T> const& l)` (or even `template<typename T> void say_all(T const& l)`) and counting on the internal usage to throw errors, you'll need to do that manually, with `enable_if` and friends.

This is something that the maybe-upcoming C++ "concepts" feature is intended to address:

```
template<typename T> requires DerivedFrom<T, Word> void say_all(list<T> const& l) { ...
```

(Note that syntax and standard library support is still subject to change).

Still, in this case that's just in service of a guaranteed, early, and easy-to-troubleshoot compiler error if you try to pass a list of something else in. Honestly, my approach here would probably be to just document that `say_all` expects a list of something subclassing `Name`, and rely on a probable compiler error if that gets violated.