# How to default-initialize std::vector<Base> with Base and Derived objects?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, stdvector

Consider the following:

```
#include <vector>

class Base 
{
public:
    Base() : x(0) {}
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
    Derived(double z0) : Base(), z(z0) {}
    double z;
};

class Foo 
{
public:
    // How to specify a default value for parameter vec0,
    // consisting of two Base objects?
    Foo(std::vector<Base> vec0 = ? ? ? ) : vec(vec0) {}
    std::vector<Base> vec;
};

class Bar 
{
public:
    // foo1.vec needs to be initialized with two Base objects.
    // foo2.vec needs to be initialized with two Derived objects.
    Bar() : foo1(? ? ? ), foo2(? ? ? ) {}
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2;
};

int main() 
{
    Bar bar;
    // Code here will want to use Base class pointers to access the elements
    // in bar.foo1.vec and bar.foo2.vec.
}
```

1. How to specify a default parameter in the Foo constructor?
2. In the `Bar` constructor *initializer list*, how to specify a vector of `Base`
   objects for `foo1`, and a vector of `Derived` objects for `foo2`?
3. How to title this question so others needing to solve this problem can find it?

Comment: You can't store a `Derived` object in a vector of `Base`s.

Comment: OK, then perhaps I should have made the vectors contain pointers to `Base`s.

Comment: "foo2.vec needs to be initialized with two Derived objects.", which value of z0 they must have? There isn't a default value.

Comment: I need an example showing them being initialized with a value. Make it 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*@sklott*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389190/initialization-of-an-aggregate-containing-vectors-of-base-and-derived-objects/57389895#57389895) 's answer explains well, how the initialization can be done using the initializer list. I would like to focus on the solution in-which `Foo` has a *vector of pointers to `Base`*. Using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`, you could rewrite *@sklott* 's solution as follows:

```
#include <memory>   // std::shared_ptr
#include <utility>  //  std::move

class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec0 = { 
              { std::make_shared<Base>(), std::make_shared<Base>() } 
           }
        )
        : vec{ std::move(vec0) } 
    {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec;
};

class Bar 
{
public:
    Bar() 
        : foo1{}  // calls Foo's default cont'r: initialized with two Base objects.
        , foo2{   // initialized with two Derived objects.
            { std::make_shared<Derived>(1.0), std::make_shared<Derived>(1.0) } 
          }
    {}
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2;
};
```

---

The above code would have *[an undefied behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)*, if we do not provide a `virtual` destructor to the `Base` class. Therefore, to make it complete solution:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    Base() : x(0) {}
    int x;
    virtual ~Base() = default;   // don't forget to provide a virtual destructor
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize `Foo.vec` using a shortened syntax indicating the size of the vector such as @sklott used with `Foo() : vec(2) {}` (instead of needing to explicitly show each vector element in the initializer list as in `{ std::make_shared<Base>(), std::make_shared<Base>() }`)? It would be useful to provide a parameter indicating the size of the vector. (I know this wasn't part of the original requirements.)

Comment: @sifferman Of course, you can:https://wandbox.org/permlink/r9c931MkBiUwy8RB. But I always prefer `std::make_shared`, for the reason explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c.

Comment: Although @sklott properly answered the question, and was  first to answer, your answer helped see me through to (I think) a better solution to my problem. Thanks. I learned some things!

Comment: It appears the construct `BasePtrVec(2, std::make_shared<Base>())` is problematic. Because it is a vector of pointers, and is constructed by creating a first `shared_ptr`, which is then copied to the remaining vector elements, we end up with a vector of shared pointers that all point to the same object.

Comment: @sifferman Yes, that exactly  I mentioned in the code(above link) as a comment: *// "vec0 is empty? construct once a `std::make_shared<Base>()` and copy to make `2` elements out of it"*. For different objects, we need to explicitly construct two different ones, like in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How to specify a default parameter in the Foo constructor?

Just use initializer list syntax, either explicitly declaring containing elements:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::vector<Base> vec0 = {Base(), Base()}) : vec(vec0) {}
    std::vector<Base> vec;
};
```

or implicitly declaring with yet another initializer list:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::vector<Base> vec0 = {{}, {}}) : vec(vec0) {}
    std::vector<Base> vec;
};
```

But if your intention is to create by default list with size 2, I think it's better to do so this way:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : vec(2) {}
    std::vector<Base> vec;
};
```

> In the Bar constructor initializer list, how to specify a vector of Base objects for foo1, and a vector of Derived objects for foo2?

You can't do this. You need to either use templates or vector of pointers.

Template example:

```
template<class V>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::vector<V> vec0 = {{}, {}}) : vec(vec0) {}
    std::vector<V> vec;
};

class Bar {
public:
    // No need to explicitly initialize foo1
    Bar() : foo2({{1.},{2.}}) {}
    Foo<Base> foo1;
    Foo<Derived> foo2;
};
```

Comment: However, using templates V could be any class.
If you want that V extends Base, you need to use std::enable_if like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687305/c-equivalent-of-using-t-extends-class-for-a-java-parameter-return-type).

Comment: @Doch88 or just `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, V>)` somewhere in `Foo`, or just use `Base`s members with `V` objects

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.