# C++ equivalent of using Entry<? extends ClassA, ? extends ClassB> getEntries() for more than two java parameter

Tags: java, c++, generics, extends

In java, I have a method:

```java
 Set<? extends Entry<? extends ClassA, ? extends ClassB>> getEntries();
```

I have read the question about [C++ equivalent of using <T extends Class> for a java parameter/return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687305/c-equivalent-of-using-t-extends-class-for-a-java-parameter-return-type),

I try as follow :

```cpp
template<typename K, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ClassA, K>::value>::type* = nullptr, typename V, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ClassB, V>::value>::type* = nullptr> set<pair<K,V>> getEntries()
```

it compile well, but I think it's lengthy and perhaps wrong. I wonder whether there is a better solution.

Comment: Why would it be different for more than one template parameter? Have you tried adapting the solution from the linked post to fit your needs?

Comment: Sorry. I try as follow : `template<typename K, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ClassA, K>::value>::type* = nullptr, typename V, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ClassB, V>::value>::type* = nullptr>
     set<pair<K,V>> getEntries();` but I think it's lengthy and perhaps wrong

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you attempted. Trying to read that in comments isn't easy.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. In fact, it's my first question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adapt the linked solution to work for yours. Your attempt (from the comments) isn't quite correct. When using `enable_if` with template parameters, it should be the last parameter, and should only appear once. So, modifying what you did to move `V` before the `enable_if`, and changing the `enable_if` to use an `&&`, you get:

```cpp
template<typename K, typename V, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ClassA, K>::value && std::is_base_of<ClassB, V>::value>::type * = nullptr> 
std::set<std::pair<K, V>> getEntries();
```

It's not pretty, ever. You can use `enable_if_t` so you don't need `::type`, but you won't save too much space. Example:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<ClassA, K> && std::is_base_of_v<ClassB, V>> * = nullptr> 
std::set<std::pair<K, V>> getEntries();
```