# How to elegantly restrict a template argument to be a `<Certain_Class<AnyT>>`?

Tags: visual-studio, c++14, template-specialization, content-assist, template-classes

How to restrict a template argument of `Wrapper` to be a `Wrapper<Any,`**`MyArray`**`<AnyT>>` elegantly?

1. Don't break content assist (Visual Studio).
2. High readability.  Not use a hacky approach.
   For some reasons, most solution love to hack.
3. Make it obvious at the very first line by using C++ syntax rule.   (not just green comment)

As far as I know, there are many solutions, but every solution doesn't meet the criteria.

### Workaround 1 (template specialization, fail 1)

```
template<class T> class MyArray{};
template<class T,class T2> class Wrapper;
template<class T,class T2> class Wrapper<T,MyArray<T2>>{     
    using Test=int; 
};
class B{};
class C{};
int main() {
    Wrapper<C,MyArray<B>> wrapper;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518221 (@max66).

Context clue / syntax highlighting of IDE will be confused.
In my case, it marks some correct types as error e.g. :-

```
class ShowError : public Wrapper<B,MyArray<C>>{ 
    Test n=0;  //<-- unknown "Test" (intellisense)
};
```

### Workaround 2 (some hacky field/typedef, fail 2)

```
template<class T> class MyArray{ 
    public: using MyArrayT=T; 
};
template<class T,class T2> class Wrapper{
    public: using myT=typename T2::MyArrayT;
    //^ assert at compile time
};
```

This idea come from a comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518295 (@Jarod42)

The class declaration doesn't mention about `MyArray`, it just uses a hacky (less readable) way (`MyArrayT`) to enforce that `T2` is `MyArray`.

### Workaround 3 (base class, fail 2)

```
class MyArrayBase{};
template<class T> class MyArray : public MyArrayBase{  };
template<class T,class T2> class Wrapper{
    //check something around MyArrayBase *object = new T2();
    // or "is_base_of"
};
```

The code is modified from [Restrict C++ Template Parameter to Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175219/restrict-c-template-parameter-to-subclass) and [C++ templates that accept only certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types).

It has same disadvantage as workaround 2.
It is not obvious for common user.

### Workaround 4 (SNIFAE, fail 1)

By adding `std::enable_if` on the template class declaration (`Wrapper`), I can get a working hack.
Unfortunately, content assist hate it.

### Reference

Here are the other links that I read :-

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878 (template template parameter)
- [restrict a template function, to only allow certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267324/restrict-a-template-function-to-only-allow-certain-types) (not related to template type as a parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom type trait `is_specialization`, as follows:

```
template<class Type, template<class...> class Template>
struct is_specialization
  : std::false_type {};
template<template<class...> class Template, class... TArgs>
struct is_specialization<Template<TArgs...>, Template>
  : std::true_type {};
```

Then you just need to `static_assert` that `is_specialization` is true for the given template argument:

```
template<class T,class T2>
class Wrapper {
    static_assert(is_specialization<T2, MyArray>::value, "T2 must be a specialization of MyArray");
};
```