# How to detect if operator[] applicable to Type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, type-traits

I would like to write function template like

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T& obj ){
    obj[0] = xxxxxx;
}
```

where T must have operator[] applicable.
T may be array of any type, std::vector, std::array, or any other type. So, I cannot use T as superclass of all of them. I think it should be something like in [std::type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) style.

Comment: What's wrong with just writing the code as is?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but if it possible I want to restrict wrong types.

Comment: @kyb Well, these will be restricted (unless you want to exclude plain pointer types). Do you want better error messages?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if someone calls `foo(1)`? As written, it's a compile-time error, which is, superficially, the appropriate response.

Comment: You are right, but I looked for something like T.C.'s answer. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T>
using LvalueIndexable = decltype(std::declval<T&>()[1]);

template<class T, class U = void>
using RequiresLvalueIndexable 
    = typename std::enable_if<std::experimental::is_detected<LvalueIndexable, T>{},
                              U>::type;

template< typename T, typename = RequiresLvalueIndexable<T> >
void foo( T& obj ){
    obj[0] = xxxxxx;
}
```

See the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) for how to implement `std::experimental::is_detected`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to restrict template types:

1) declare the function template as a private class method and then call it from public overloaded methods, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/27043/);

2) using Boost static assert and `is_base_of` to compare template and types, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874337);

3) or include `type_traits` and use asserts `static_assert(is_same<T, float>::value, "Error message");`