# Template specialization: C++ templates that only accept certain types (revisited)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I want to make a simple message template class as follows. I followed the structure verbatim from the [chosen answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types). However, this seems to break in Visual Studio 2013.

```
template<typename T> Message;

template<> Message <std::vector<uint8_t>>
{
public:

};

template<> Message <std::string>
{

};
```

IntelliSense tells me that `Message is not a template`.

Placing `class` before `Message` in the forward declaration results in a slightly better, but equally annoying IntelliSense error: `expected and identifier`after the opening brace `{` of each template.

```
template<typename T> class Message;

template<> Message <std::vector<uint8_t>>
{
public:

};

template<> Message <std::string>
{

};
```

I should note that all the above code is currently being placed in a header file.

Comment: That should work (second posted code)! Beware that older c++ compilers needs to insert space in between `>>` thus `> >`. Is `<vector>` header included? Post the full error messages.

Comment: Place `class` before `Message` everywhere (both in declaration and specializations).

Comment: linked answer fixed too.

Comment: Now How would I add, say a function which returns `T` or a member of type `T`>. `const T getKey() { return key; };` does not work, nor does `T key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `class` keyword in the template specialization as well. I don't know why the linked answer doesn't do that.

```
template<typename T> class Message;

template<> class Message <std::vector<uint8_t>>
{
public:

};

template<> class Message <std::string>
{

};
```