# Adding parameters to forward-declared templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

As per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107797/template-specialization-c-templates-that-only-accept-certain-types-revisited), I'd like to do the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T> class Message;

template<> class Message <std::vector<uint8_t>>
{
public:
    const T getKey() { return key; };
    const T getMessage() { return message; };

protected:
    T key;
    T message;
};
```

However, IntelliSense tells me that `identifier "T" is undefined"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to substitute `T` by `std::vector<uint8_t>` everywhere in your specialization:

```
template<> class Message <std::vector<uint8_t>>
{
public:
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& getKey() const { return key; };
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& getMessage() const { return message; };

protected:
    std::vector<uint8_t> key;
    std::vector<uint8_t> message;
};
```

I also add missing `const` and references.

Comment: One could also add a `using T = std::vector<uint8_t>;` statement.