# How to define a template function that only accepts types with a defined API

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

```
template<typename T>
void Func(T& writer)
{
  try
  {
    writer.open("hello.log");
  }
  catch (std::exception & ex) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types

Question> Is it possible that I can define the template function `Func` only accepts a type with well-defined `open` interface?

Thank you

Comment: It already will; if you try to provide something that doesn't support `open` with those parameters, it will fail to compile.  If you want cleaner error messages, you will need to wait for C++20 [Concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you not know how to check if some type has a member function or do you not know how to produce an error message out of that information?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I want the caller to know that this template function only accepts a type that has a defined `open`.

Comment: @q0987 The compiler will tell them as it stands. I still don't know what you are trying to achieve. What does / doesn't it do now that it should not / should?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types, basically, I wanted to add some traits information so that the caller doesn't have to compile the code before they know that the type must have a defined `open` API.

Comment: So, just use a comment. The language stuff gets enforced by the compiler and is, as you don't want to use it, of no use here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I just made things a little complicated than it should be. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear why do you want to do this but... if you declare (no needs to define) a couple of helper functions

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto withOpenHelper (int)
   -> decltype(std::declval<T>().open(std::declval<Args>()...),
               std::true_type{} );

template <typename ... Args>
constexpr std::false_type withOpenHelper (long);
```

and a `using` to simplify the use

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
using withOpen = decltype( withOpenHelper<T, Args...>(0) );
```

you can SFINAE enable/disable `Func()` only if `T` support a `open()` receiving a `std::string`

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<withOpen<T, std::string>::value> Func (T & writer)
 {
   // something
 }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A { int open (std::string const &) { return 0; } };
struct B {  };

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto withOpenHelper (int)
   -> decltype(std::declval<T>().open(std::declval<Args>()...),
               std::true_type{} );

template <typename ... Args>
constexpr std::false_type withOpenHelper (long);

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
using withOpen = decltype( withOpenHelper<T, Args...>(0) );

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<withOpen<T, std::string>::value> Func (T & writer)
 {
      writer.open("hello.log");
 }

int main ()
 {
   A a;
   B b;

   Func(a);
   //Func(b); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Not sure how this would be better than what they already have.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You can `static_assert` with cleaner error message.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - so do I... I don't understand what exactly want the OP... but I suppose that, this way, he can develop different `Func()` functions for different types (one for classes with `open()` with a `std::string` argument, one for classes with `open()` with two `int` arguments, one for classes with `open2()`, etc.)