# C++ template specialization in subtemplates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In *json.h* I have:

```
template <class T>
Json::Value write_json(const T& object);
```

In *json.cpp*:

```
template <>
Json::Value write_json(const bool& object) {
    Json::Value output;
    output = object;
    return output;
};

template <>
Json::Value write_json(const int& object) {
    Json::Value output;
    output = object;
    return output;
};

template <>
Json::Value write_json(const std::vector<bool>& v) {
    Json::Value output;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) { output.append(*it); };
    return output;
};

template <>
Json::Value write_json(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    Json::Value output;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) { output.append(*it); };
    return output;
};
```

Is there any way in *C++* to specialize basic types on one "subtemplate" and containers on another?

Comment: Please refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types).

Comment: @ZMJ the other question is indeed only similar. The response there is about classes for which partial specialization is available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## C++17 Solution

Let's start with trait to check if you are getting container or not:

```
template<class ...>
using void_t = void;    

template<class T, class = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct is_container<T, void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>())), decltype(std::end(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type{};

template<class T>
constexpr auto is_container_v = is_containter<T>::value;
```

With that you can just do:

```
template <class T>
Json::Value write_json_primitive(const T& object) {
    static_assert(!is_container_v<T>);
    Json::Value output;
    output = object;
    return output;
};

template <class T>
Json::Value write_json_container(const T& v) {
    static_assert(is_container_v<T>);
    Json::Value output;
    for (const auto& val : v) { output.append(val); };
    return output;
};

template <class T>
Json::Value write_json(const T& object) {
    if constexpr (is_container_v<T>)
        return write_json_container(object);
    else
        return write_json_primitive(object);
}
```

Sidenote: this code requires C++17 support. If you need explicitly C++11 it can be done but a bit differently

## C++ 11 Solution

A bit more metaprogramming is needed here and `static_asserts` cannot be used so easily but still I did it:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

    
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type{};
    
template<class T>
struct is_container<T, void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>())), decltype(std::end(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type{};

template <class T>
Json::Value write_json_primitive(const T& object) {
    Json::Value output;
    output = object;
    return output;
};

template <class T>
Json::Value write_json_container(const T& v) {
    Json::Value output;
    for (const auto& val : v) { output.append(val); };
    return output;
};


template<class T>
using json_function = std::conditional<
        is_container<T>::value,
            std::integral_constant<decltype(&write_json_container<T>), &write_json_container<T>>,
            std::integral_constant<decltype(&write_json_primitive<T>), &write_json_primitive<T>>>;

template <class T>
Json::Value write_json(const T& object) {
    return json_function<T>::type::value(object);
}
```

This hopefully will work like a charm ;)

Comment: How about range-iteration through containers?

Comment: You mean "If you need explicitly C++11 it **can't** be done", right?

Comment: @Pierre no, I meant it can be done, just in a bit more complicated way

Comment: @bartop Unfortunately, I need explicitly C++11

Comment: @Medicalphysicist ok, you made me sweat writing it but the job is done I hope ;)