# Is it possible to restrict a template?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Restrict Template Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148373/c-restrict-template-function)
>   [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Is it possible to restrict the types for which a template may be instantiated
(that is, have a compiler error if I use `template<type_not_allowed>`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to provide no default implementation, and specialize your class template only on those types you wish to allow.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class X> class Gizmo
{
public:
    Gizmo();
};

template<> Gizmo<int>::Gizmo()
{
}

int main()
{
    Gizmo<float> gf; // ERROR:  No specialization for Gizmo<float> results in a linking error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the constructor private in the illegal type:

```
template<typename T>
class Z
{
public:
    Z() {}
};

template<>
class Z<int>
{
private:
    Z();
};

Z<float> f; // OK
Z<int>   i; // Compile time error.
```

Comment: I wonder if leaving the specialization incomplete wouldn't be simpler and still do the trick?

Comment: @UncleBens, that would produce a linker error (I think this is what you mean: `template<> class Z<int> { public: Z(); };`. As I have it above it produces a compiler error, earlier detection.

Comment: No, I mean `template <> class Z<int>;` You shouldn't be able to instantiate an incomplete type at compile time. (Basically the same - but reversed - as the accepted answer, if the base template was left incomplete.)

Comment: @UncleBens, yes that is an improvement on mine. Less effort to code and compile time error. Cheers.