# How do I constrain a template parameter to comply to a Key in std::map?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constraints, stdmap

I have a class template that intends to use its parameter K as the key to a map.

**Is there any way to restrict the template parameter to be a type that complies with the Key in std::map?**

I realize that even without such constraint, the compiler would spit out a pile of template errors like K having no `operator < ()`, but it would be nice if I can make my code more obvious in specifying requirements.

C++11 solutions are welcome.

```
template< typename K >
class Foo
{
  // lots of other code here...

  private:
    std::map< K, size_t > m_map;
};
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148373/c-restrict-template-function   If it is not the same question, it at least answers it.

Comment: What behavior is expected if the "K" is passed which doesn't go well with std::map?

Comment: @JoeMcGrath +1 for a helpful link - too bad STL doesn't seem to have something like this: http://libcds.sourceforge.net/doc/cds-api/structcds_1_1map_1_1key__traits.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "complies."  If you want to verify that `K` has a `<` operator then you might try the [Boost Concept Checking Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).

```
#include "boost/concept_check.hpp"

template< typename K >
class Foo
{
  BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::LessThanComparable< K >));

  // lots of other code here...

  private:
    std::map< K, size_t > m_map;
};
```

However if you want to verify that `<` defines a StrictWeakOrdering on `K`, that would require testing run-time behaviour under all possible inputs.

Comment: I believe that keys must also be copy contructable or moveable in C++11.

Comment: @Omnifarious this is part of the problem - the requirements are not obvious without some previous magic knowledge (magic in the sense that it's not in the code - at least not obvious in the code).  Also, Andrew's comment is pertinent: we still can't seem to know if we've implemented our custom Class's ordering properly at compile time: we still need to run some test to ensure that it's working right.

Comment: +1 to Andrew for mentioning Boost::Concepts - I guess this is one of the features that `didn't` make it into C++11...

Comment: The only problem is that you'd still get lots of "no `operator<`" errors, and then this brilliant error mentioning problems with LessThenComparable.

Comment: @kfmfe04 Yes, unfortunately Concepts were dropped from the new standard.  See [ConceptGCC](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptGCC/) for an implementation (but I believe it's no longer maintained).

Comment: @AndrewDurward +1 tyvm for the tip - I will try it out!

Comment: @kfmfe04: And Boost::Concepts is not that feature. It is a (by necessity) kludgey attempt to imitate a part of the feature with existing compiler constructs.

Answer (score 5):

C++11 version:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct satisfies_key_req{
  struct nat{};

  template<class K> static auto test(K* k) -> decltype(*k < *k);
  template<class K> static nat  test(...);

  static bool const value = !std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(0)), nat>::value;
};

#include <iostream>

struct foo{};

int main(){
    static bool const b = satisfies_key_req<int>::value;
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    static bool const b2 = satisfies_key_req<foo>::value;
    std::cout << b2 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

---

The key point I used here is *expression SFINAE*: `auto test(K* k) -> decltype(*k < *k)`. If the expression in the trailing-return-type is not valid, then this particular overload of `test` is removed from the overload set. In other words, it's SFINAE'd.

`§14.8.2 [temp.deduct]`

> p6 **At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template arguments.** This is done at the beginning of template argument deduction when any explicitly specified template arguments are substituted into the function type, and **again at the end of template argument deduction when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted**.
>
> p7 **The substitution occurs in all types and expressions** that are used in the function type and in template parameter declarations. **The expressions include not only constant expressions** such as those that appear in array bounds or as nontype template arguments **but also general expressions** (i.e., non-constant expressions) **inside** `sizeof`, **`decltype`**, and other contexts that allow non-constant expressions.
>
> p8 If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed if written using the substituted arguments. [...]

---

You can use it in three flavors for your `Foo` class to trigger an error.

```
// static_assert, arguably the best choice
template< typename K >
class Foo
{
  static_assert<satisfies_key_req<K>::value, "K does not satisfy key requirements");
  // lots of other code here...

  private:
    std::map< K, size_t > m_map;
};

// new-style SFINAE'd, maybe not really clear
template<
  typename K,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<
               satisfies_key_req<K>::value
             >::type
>
class Foo
{
  // lots of other code here...

  private:
    std::map< K, size_t > m_map;
};

// partial specialization, clarity similar to SFINAE approach
template< 
  typename K,
  bool = satisfies_key_req<K>::value
>
class Foo
{
  // lots of other code here...

  private:
    std::map< K, size_t > m_map;
};

template<typename K>
class Foo<K, false>;
```

Comment: +1 v.nice!  I need some time to think about your solution to digest its implications...  ...maybe improve this with static_assert() to ensure that we catch problems during compile time?

Comment: @kfmfe04: I only provided the type trait, if you use it in a `static_assert` or newstyle SFINAE, or even in a construct like shown in other answers (partial specialization) to trigger a compiler error is something for you to decide. :) All three would work, and I think `static_assert` is the clearest. Note that currently only Clang has the correct output, MSVC and the GCC versions I could test all don't trigger SFINAE on `-> decltype(k < k)` yet, even though it's legal and standard C++. I'll edit in some explanations soon.

Answer (score 2):

A complete solution to your problem probably is impossible. But I can suggest you a solution, if you want to restrict `K` to be a specific type you can define your class as follows

```
template <class K, bool = std::is_same<K,int>::value>
class Foo { ... };

template <class K>
class Foo<K,false> { Foo(); };
```

So if `K` is `int` your class works as expected. Otherwise you can not costruct object of type `Foo<K>`. Obviously you can refine the condition.

To check if `K` has the `operator<` you can use `boost::has_less`, but as you can check in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_less.html) this traits doesn't work properly always.

Comment: You can use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` or C++11 `static_assert` instead of that template hack there

Comment: @bdonlan +1 for mentioning `static_assert`.  +1 to mattia for mentioning `boost::has_less` and for adding elaboration link.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I guess you want one suitable error instead of loads of errors.

Following code finds, if a type has a valid `operator <` or not:

```
namespace OperatorExist
{
  typedef char no[3]; // '3' can be any awkward number
  template<typename T> no& operator < (const T&, const T&);

  template<typename T>
  struct LessThan {
    static const bool value = (sizeof(*(T*)(0) < *(T*)(0)) != sizeof(no));
  };
}
```

Now, you can specialize `class Foo` using the above construct:

```
template<typename K, bool = OperatorExist::LessThan<K>::value>
class Foo 
{
  // lots of other code here...
  private:
    std::map<K, size_t> m_map;
};

template<typename K>
class Foo<K, false>; // unimplemented for types not suitable for 'std::map'
```

As soon as you use some type `A` which doesn't have compatibility with `std::map`, the compiler will complain with single error:

```
error: aggregate ‘Foo<A> oa’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/vEKyp)

Comment: You are right - I'm looking for a more friendly way to warn users of class `Foo` - interesting implementation, with nice error msgs!