# Good Practice for Templated Classes and Handling Unwanted Type Declarations

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, coding-style

What is considered "good practice" in handling unwanted data types for templated classes?

Let's say we have a function in a templated class that does number multiplication, but the driver file for the class declares an instance of the class with Type `string`.

I've been given the argument that this is a "personal problem" for whoever's creating the driver file, and that all that needs to be done on your part is proper function prologues in the header/implementation files.

I'm wondering if there is a general practice used with templates regarding this issue. Do you check your Types in a class before handling them (I guess, to a certain extent that defeats the purpose of a template), or do you define behavior for specific types (though this also seems like a defeat of purpose)?

Or do you simply document your code correctly and let the programmer who uses your class take the precautions?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148373/c-restrict-template-function

Comment: @GuillaumeSchub That was a specific case on restricting certain data types. I'm asking a wider-scope question; wondering what common practices are applied with this type of situation, where you want to account for cases (if at all) of what could be considered an incorrect data type.

Answer (score 2):

I'd generally use something like Boost/C++11 [`static_assert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) to assert the properties you want This will not only let you assure that it's numeric, but has things like is_signed and is_integer to assure more detail about the type, if you need/want to.